# Notification when AVQueuePlayer rewinds to the beginning of an item

Tags: ios

I have 5 `AVPlayerItems` in my `AVQueuePlayer`, which is set to `AVPlayerActionAtItemEndAdvance`. I hit play on my UI, and play the first, the second and then start playing the third. Then I hit my rewind button. What I want to happen is that the third video rewinds to its start, and I then get a notification that allows me to stop. What I'm seeing is that I get a status of ready to play for the 4th item, followed by a current item changed to the 4th item - then the 4th item plays.

Why does the 4th item become the current item after the 3rd item has rewound to its start

Is the only way I can stop this to set the player to not auto advance (`AVPlayerActionAtItemEndPause`), observe the end of each item, and hope I get an "end of play" notification for the rewinding of the 3rd item  as well as when it plays to its end naturally. Then in my end observer code, I can check the rate of the player, and if rewinding, not advance to the next item.

Answer (score 0):

The way I handled this was in the begin seeking code, set the `actionAtItemEnd` to `AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone`, and then reset it back to `AVPlayerActionAtItemEndAdvance` when the seeking ends. On iOS6, it appears that one can seek past the start of the track. In the "end seeking" code, I reset the rate and current time before beginning normal playback.

The following method is called by a long press gesture recognizer.

```
- (IBAction)fastRewind:(id)sender
{
    UIGestureRecognizer *recog = (UIGestureRecognizer*)sender;
    if (recog.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        if (_player.rate == 1) {
            NSLog(@"fastRewind begin\n%@", sender);
            _player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
            _player.rate = -2;
        }
    } else if (recog.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        // Ended/Canceled
        NSLog(@"fastRewind end\n%@", sender);
        if (_player.rate < 0) {
            _player.rate = 0;
            if (CMTimeGetSeconds(_player.currentTime) < 0) {
                [_player seekToTime:CMTimeMake(0, 1)];
            }
            _player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndAdvance;
            _player.rate = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

One may wish to speed up the seek if it is held for a longer period of time.